# How do I load a single image with multiple images on it?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an image file that has multiple different images on it.  I was wondering how to make it so that I can load the individual images from the single one instead of breaking each into its own thing.  Sorry if I couldn't clarify what I am trying to ask.

Comment: You will need to go through the process of "cutting" the image with some algorithm.

Comment: this is related, is the same question but not with pygame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059217/cutting-one-image-into-multiple-images-using-the-python-image-library

Comment: here's a similar one with pygame: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239769/crop-an-image-in-pygame-get-a-new-surface

Comment: You're looking for a [SpriteSheet](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet?parent=CookBook)

Answer (score 0):

You could load it all as one image and than draw the different segments onto the screen separately, or even define variables of the segments. This would effectively give you multiple images.