# Pillow cutting image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How could I cut one image into other images using pillow if I have a given row and column.

For example if I have an image with a row = 4 and a column = 4, I need the image to be cut into 16 pieces. (4x4) The pieces all need to have the same size so I could fix that by adding a border to the image but I don't know how to do that with pillow.

Pseudocode will do!

Comment: Cutting? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6059217/2564301. Adding border? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11142851/2564301. Size for each tile? `(im.size[0] + column-1)//column`, and the same for `[1]` and `row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a
   [new](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.new)
   image of the correct size and colour to act as a background.
2. [Paste](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) the original image into it.
3. Use [crop](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) to get your sub-rectangles.